# Контравариантность дженериков

Tags: наследование

Всем привет.
Википедия и другие статьи говорят нам, что запись рода `List<? super Number>` контравариантна. Однако, в подобный лист я могу беспрепятственно добавлять не только предков `Number`, но и любых наследников `Number`, например `Integer`, а это уже ковариантность. Получается, что работают оба свойства. То есть, нельзя сказать, что самая первая запись только контравариантна, верно?

Comment: Насколько понимаю, Integer в данном случае вставится не как Integer, а как Number или Object, потому что ими он является тоже.

Answer (score 1):

Контрвариантность относится к типу `List<? super Number>` целиком, а не только к типу элементов этого списка.

Вот простой пример

```
public void doIt() {
    List<Integer> listOfInteger = new LinkedList<>();
    List<Number> listOfNumber = new LinkedList<>();
    List<Object> listOfObject = new LinkedList<>();


    contr(listOfInteger); // ошибка
    contr(listOfNumber);
    contr(listOfObject);
}

public void contr(List<? super Number> l) {
    l.add(1);
    Object object = l.get(0);
    Number number = l.get(0); // ошибка
}
```